# flutter making authenticated api requests

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do something along these lines to make an authenticated api request:

```
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
  return http.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1',
    // Send authorization headers to the backend.
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic your_api_token_here"},
  );
}
```

I get my api tokens by calling

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password).
```

My questions are:

1. Don't these tokens expire after a short period of time?  How do I make it so my user doesn't have to constantly log in?  I don't understand this at all.
2. Should I save my user variable in a global provider state and access it this way?

I've been watching tons of tutorials on this and I don't get it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the two pieces of code you shared relate to each other, nor how this all relates to Cloud Functions (which you tagged with). Can you update your question to clarify these?

Comment: saving your _email and _password (or token in other cases) in shared preference (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) would be the way.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for helping out.  I don't understand this in the awss stack either.  Basically, how do I make authenticated api calls when I log in with the above code?  Don't the tokens refresh?  How do I account for that?